# How to show the page header, when we click on the verticl tab using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### HTML:

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#a1">a1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b1">b1</a></li>          
    </ul>
    <div id="sections">
    <div class="section" id="a">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="b">
    </div>
```

My demo link: http://www.bajistech.info/tiltindicators.html#TiltWatch-Plus1, I'm trying to make page scroll when I click on the vertical tab.

### Script 1:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        //$('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() {
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function() { 
            showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
        });
  // if hash found then load the tab from Hash id
        if(window.location.hash) 
        {
   // to get the div id
           showSection( window.location.hash);
        }
        else // if no hash found then default first tab is opened
        {
            $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

### Script 2

```
function showSection( sectionID ) {
    $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
    $('div'+sectionID).css( 'display', 'block' );
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        //$('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() { // no need for each loop
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function() { // Use $('ul#verticalNav li a').click
            showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
        });
        //});
        if(window.location.hash) // if hash found then load the tab from Hash id
        {
           showSection( window.location.hash);// to get the div id
        }
        else // if no hash found then default first tab is opened
        {
            $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following style "**overflow:hidden**;" and remove the **height** property for the div with the classname **about_content_forproducttilt10**
Also it's a good choice to use more generic classnames, in your case "product description" insteand on "about_content_forproduct..."

Comment: Hi N1KKOU, thank you so much. how i can show the webpage header. plz check my screenshot :http://www.bajistech.info/productimage/scrollpage.jpg thanks.

Comment: I need to see the mark-up to help you. But anyway, you should rely more on browser natural flow(using dislay block & inline-block) rather then on floats.